# Sorting blocks of text in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Using bash and typically available unix commands, how can I sort "blocks" of text in a file, where a "block" is a set of lines separated by blank lines?

For example, these two items would be reversed.

```
item b:
    b stuff

item a:
    a stuff
```

Comment: I think that using `sort` command with blank line as a separator will do the magic.

Comment: From the link above: perl has a 'paragraph mode'  which splits input on empty lines. Here's a demo on tio: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsIwEETv@xUjCr1Y2rMW8WBvUj9BdiWhgRpDsj1Jvz2m1LnNewMjnMac97tGnG@kFKIXKy7WTQZdh/5xJ6fmDTkRSgRJZ2tpg7xB/sN1TMHECbVvW9QGVZjTiCsfcXie0Q83fBGi84r0iVoElgrrV84/ "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU tools, you can sort text blocks that end with a NUL ASCII character (instead of a newline).

The idea below is to add that NUL character after each block (with `gawk`), sort the result (with `sort -z`) and then remove that NUL character (with `tr`):

```
gawk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n\0' 1 input_file.txt \
| sort -z \
| tr -d '\0'
```

Note: this may add an empty line at the end of the file; you can remove it with `... | sed '$ d'` (or `... | head -n -1` with GNU head).